# How to write the array procedure function here?

Tags: java, arrays

```
   double arr[] = new double[j];


   for (int i=0; i<j; i++)
   {
       arr[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please insert the value : "));


   }
   double result = calc.average(arr[i]);  // How can I return here?
```

How can I call the function of public double `average(int[] arr)` in the main function, if there is an array?

Comment: Can you show some more code? The function `average` including declaration and the main method?

Comment: `calc.average(arr);` ???

Comment: public double[] swap(double arr[])
 {
  double temp = 0;
  
  temp = arr[0];
  arr[0] = arr[1];
  arr[1] = temp;
  
  return arr;
 }    //Function class

Comment: int j = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please insert how many you wanted to calculate :"));
  
    double arr[] = new double[j];
    
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++)
    {
     arr[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please insert the value : "));
    
     
    }
    double result = calc.average(arr[i]);  //This is in the main class

Comment: I just do not know how to call the function in array...can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

logically it should be done the other way around. have a function to calculate the sum of the array call that function in the average method then divide the answer returned from sum by the number of elements in the array.

Since the above method has only input, the full array should be sent to another method called average (not just one array element) the average method then uses a method called sum by passing the array there and receiving the sum. then working out the average as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass the entire array to the method, you need to pass `arr` :

```
double result = calc.average(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to declare this method as `static` so you can call it in your main, then in your main you write the code that fill the array and you pass this array to your `average` method, here's how should be your code:

```
public class Calcul {

    public static void average(int[] array) {
        //do your job here
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Calcul calc = new Calcul();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please insert how many you wanted to calculate :")); 
        double arr[] = new double[j]; 
        for (int i=0; i<j; i++) { 
             arr[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please insert the value : ")); 
        } 
        //here's how to call your method.
        double result = calc.average(arr); 
    }
}
```